# Segmentation Fault trying to recursively solve maze

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, maze

here is my code. I have read how to do recursive algorithms to solve a maze and this should work but I keep getting a segmentation fault and I don't know why. If you can help me that would be great. Thanks.

```
bool FindPath(Maze& m, int x, int y){

    RoomType rt = m.GetRoomType(x,y);

    if (rt == RoomType::Outside)
        return false;

    if (rt == RoomType::Treasure){
        return true; 
    }

    if (rt == RoomType::Wall)
        return false;


    m.MarkPath(x,y);

    if (FindPath(m,x,y-1) == true){
        return true;
    }

    if (FindPath(m,x+1,y) == true){
        return true;
    }

    if (FindPath(m,x,y+1) == true){
        return true;
    }

    if (FindPath(m,x-1,y) == true){
        return true;
    }

    m.ClearPath(x,y);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tag it as C++. As the fault is not in this code. Why not try the debugger

Comment: you dont seem to avoid stepping on a marked path, this will lead to infinite recursion

Comment: "[T]his should work." The first step to successful debugging is wiping that thought from your mind. It does not work for a reason - that you just have to find.

Answer (score 1):

`FindPath()` doesn't seem to avoid entering the same room repeatedly, which easily leads to loops in the tested path. For example it will try to repeatedly go forward and backward between two adjacent rooms, infinitely.

This leads to deeper and deeper recursion, in the end causing a stack overflow. This is stack overflow is probably the cause of the segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if x and y are in bounds at the top of the function, this should solve your crash.

Comment: the path marking is probably also to avoid trying the same thing several times

Comment: no I think his using to mark the correct path since there's no logic like if x,y is marked, then return.

Comment: its the lack of that checking that is probably the real bug, bounds checking seems to already be there ( `RoomType::Outside` )

Comment: That depends on how he implemented GetRoomType.  If he's doing m.rooms[x][y].type or something then it will crash.  If he's doing bounds checking inside that function and returning outside if x and y are out of range, then it does take care of it.  You're right that the marked path needs to be checked and not traversed again, otherwise it will lead to infinite loop causing stack depth to exceed max for circular paths that don't hit a wall.  So he'll probably hit that problem next after the seg fault is resolved.